# How can I update a content item (draft) from a background task in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, background-process

I have a simple `IBackgroundTask` implementation that performs a query and then either performs an insert or one or more updates depending on whether a specific item exists or not. However, the *updates* are not persisted, and I don't understand why. *New items* are created just as expected.

The content item I'm updating has a `CommonPart` and I've tried authenticating as a valid user. I've also tried flushing the content manager at the end of the `Sweep` method. What am I missing?

This is my `Sweep`, slightly edited for brevity:

```
public void Sweep()
{
    // Authenticate as the site's super user
    var superUser = _membershipService.GetUser(_orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentSite.SuperUser);
    _authenticationService.SetAuthenticatedUserForRequest(superUser);

    // Create a dummy "Person" content item
    var item = _contentManager.New("Person");
    var person = item.As<PersonPart>();
    if (person == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    person.ExternalId = Random.Next(1, 10).ToString();
    person.FirstName = GenerateFirstName();
    person.LastName = GenerateLastName();

    // Check if the person already exists
    var matchingPersons = _contentManager
        .Query<PersonPart, PersonRecord>(VersionOptions.AllVersions)
        .Where(record => record.ExternalId == person.ExternalId)
        .List().ToArray();
    if (!matchingPersons.Any())
    {
        // Insert new person and quit
        _contentManager.Create(item, VersionOptions.Draft);
        return;
    }

    // There are at least one matching person, update it
    foreach (var updatedPerson in matchingPersons)
    {
        updatedPerson.FirstName = person.FirstName;
        updatedPerson.LastName = person.LastName;
    }

    _contentManager.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions in app_data\logs?

Comment: Nope. There is an error .log file for this date but it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `_contentManager.Publish(updatedPerson)`. If you do not want to publish, but just to save, you don't need to do anything more, as changes in Orchard as saved automatically unless the ambient transaction is aborted. The call to `Flush` is not necessary at all. This is the case both during a regular request and on a background task.

Comment: Then it should just work, no need to flush. Does the same code work in a regular controller, not in a background task?

Comment: Ok I feel like an idiot now - the code I posted works. In my actual program the model has more properties, some of which where not set in the background task. It so happened that I looked at exactly those properties when I checked whether the update had been persisted or not... I had forgotten about the commented-out code.

Comment: Strictly _contentManager.Publish() had nothing to do with the issue (since there were no issue). I appreciate that you took the time to answer though. If I could give you as a user an upvote, I would, but I'm not marking this particular post as an answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with the additional elements I had only provided in comments: the answer may not have been what you expected, but the comments did give you the solution to your problem.